# Problematic installation of AlmaLinux/CentOS

Tags: linux, centos, ilo

I am trying to install AlmaLinux/CentOS 8 on a new HP ProLiant DL360p Gen8 server via iLO 4 (firmware version 2.77)

Everything seems to be ok; and I can even see the typical interactive anaconda installer screen which asks if I want to test my installation media before proceeding. Unfortunately, the problems begin there. The screen either goes blank - or by using a Java Applet to access the iLO remote management screen, can display a rather strange kernel panic error. [See the image attached.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4I3Oo.png)

If anybody can point me in the right direction I'd be very grateful. Kudos in advance! Thanks.

Comment: First step is to update or reinstall the BIOS and other firmware. The message "the BIOS has corrupted" anything _should never happen_ and indicates exactly that: that the BIOS is corrupt. It may also be that the EEPROM holding the BIOS is bad, in which case it would have to be replaced.

Comment: While we're here, where did you find a _new_ nine year old server?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comments. The server is "new" but bought in refurbished. What should I be looking to obtain, HP Drivers/Firmware?

Comment: Problem was fixed. Not sure if I installed the Service Pack but I went through all the screens and bam, it's working.